# Migrating from Office365 P1 to E1

Tags: email, exchange, migration, office365

I am looking at moving my domain from Office365 P1 to E1 because I need full control of my DNS, and a P1 plan requires you to use the Microsoft DNS servers... So, I am now looking at moving to an E1 plan, but have been told the following:

- No easy migration plan
- when domain is removed from an P1, it could take 24 hours before it can be moved to E1...
- Email, SharePoint and Lync will be down during this 24 hours...

I don't mind SharePoint and Lync being down too much, i can cope with that, but Email being down is kind of painful...

So, my question: How do i move both DNS and Mail servers without loosing email access?

Comment: noted... thanks for the feedback. going to tweak the question...

Comment: Downvote removed since the question is now on topic.